# Edit images in PDF file using COSStream object

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, javax.imageio

I try to edit images in PDF file using PDFBox library. How I have example working only for jpeg images. ImageIO.read() fails to decode images with 'png' suffix. Here is code example. So my question: how to do the same for all types of images in PDF documents? Can I still use ImageIO for it or need another approach?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("docs/input1.pdf");

    // Get all images from first page 
    Map<String, PDXObjectImage> pageImages = ((PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0)).getResources().getImages();
    if (pageImages != null) 
    {
        // iterate by images
        Iterator<String> imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
        while (imageIter.hasNext()) 
        {
            String key =  imageIter.next();

            PDXObjectImage image = pageImages.get(key); // get page image object
            String suffix = image.getSuffix();  // get image suffix
            String imageName = key+'.'+suffix;  // compose image name

            System.out.print("process "+imageName+"... ");

            COSStream s = image.getCOSStream(); // get COSStream to manipulate
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(s.getFilteredStream()); // get BufferedImage to edit

            if(img == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't decode");
            }
            else
            {
                paint(img.createGraphics()); // draw on it
                ImageIO.write(img, suffix, new File("out/"+imageName)); // write file to check result...

                // encode image back to COSStream
                OutputStream out = s.createFilteredStream();
                ImageIO.write(img, suffix, out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("done");
            }
        }
    }
    doc.save("out/output1.pdf"); // save document
}   

/**
 * Draw red rectangular to test
 * @param g graphics
 */
public static void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    int xpoints[] = {25, 245, 245, 25};
    int ypoints[] = {25, 25, 545, 545};
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 4);
}
```

Comment: Can you dump the contents of `s` (the `COSStream`) to disk, and see if other tools can read it, and perhaps add a link to the PNG from the question? ImageIO should be able to read PNGs just fine, without anything extra.

Comment: Thanks for hint! First I tried it on jpeg images and for jpegs here is jpeg format in getFilteredStream() result. Now I check this for png and in this case stream is very different and definitely not in png format. After some experiments I can say using ImageIO is wrong. To get BufferedImage here is .getRGBImage() method and to write result back most simple way I found is to create temporary object of the same class as original image and give BufferedImage to constructor, then copy stream of temporary object to target object (using .getFilteredStream() and .createFilteredStream()).

Comment: Alright! :-) If you have a solution, consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to work not with stream of PDXObjectImage but create new instance of PDXObjectImage and replace it in resources collection. It's more generic and universal way. Use getRGBImage() to convert PDXObjectImage to BufferedImage and constructor (PDPixelMap, PDJpeg etc) to convert edited result back to PDXObjectImage. Note you still have problems with JBIG2 and Jpeg2000 images due to bugs. Here is code example I use to find and convert all images in document:

```
// Recursive resource processor
// Here can be images inside in PDXObjectForm objects
protected static void processResources(PDResources resources, PDDocument doc, String filename) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, JBIG2Exception, ColorSpaceException, ICCProfileException
{
    if(resources == null) return;
    Map<String, PDXObject> xObjects = resources.getXObjects();
    if (xObjects == null) return;

    // iterate by images
    Iterator<String> imageIter = xObjects.keySet().iterator();
    while (imageIter.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key =  imageIter.next();

        PDXObject o = xObjects.get(key);

        if(o instanceof PDXObjectImage)
            xObjects.put(key, processImage((PDXObjectImage) o /*, some additional parms... */));

        if(o instanceof PDXObjectForm)
            processResources(((PDXObjectForm) o).getResources(), doc, filename);
    }

    resources.setXObjects(xObjects);
}
```

Note resources.setXObjects() call at the end - without it changes you made in collection obtained by resources.getXObjects() will not be written back to document.

Comment: JBIG2 works if you add the levigo JBIG2 plugin to your classpath. JPEG2000 works "most of the time" with java imageio.

Comment: Yes, levigo JBIG2 works fine. Decoding of JPEG2000 1-bit still problematic.

Comment: If the file isn't confidential, please email it to me or upload it somewhere; even if I can't solve the problem, it will be a useful test file for PDFBox in the future.